# What is grammatical role of "past"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

In the following sentence:

> We see pulses of light each time the beam sweeps **past** the Earth.

What is the grammatical role of "past" and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a preposition and it means **by**.